# how can i place javascript data attribute in form_input() codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

this is my code,
how can i place javascript data attribute in form_input()  codeigniter??

```
$experience=array(
    'name'=>'experience',
    'class'=>'slider tags',
    'id'=>'experience',
    'data-slider-min'=>1,
    'data-slider-max'=>15,
    'data-slider-step'=>1,
    'data-slider-value'=>[5,10]
);
echo form_input($experience); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code it might help you to overcome this issue

```
                        <?php
                        $experience=array(
                            'name'=>'experience',
                            'class'=>'slider tags',
                            'id'=>'experience',
                            'data-slider-min'=>0,
                            'data-slider-max'=>15,
                            'data-slider-step'=>1,
                            'data-slider-value'=>['5','10'],
                            'value'=>3,4

                        );
                      echo form_input($experience); 
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply moving your JS attributes into the $experience variable that you use to create the input?

```
$experience=array(
    'name'=>'experience',
    'class'=>'slider tags',
    'id'=>'experience',
    'data-slider-min' => 1,
    'data-slider-max' => 15,
);
```

etc...

Comment: @M.Athishkrishna Can you please show your newly edited code in your original post?

Comment: Have you seen that?@Leprichaun

Comment: Put single quotes around the last attribute, just like you did with name, id and class. The numbers don't need quotes, but the last one does as it's treated as a string.

Comment: No worries my friend. Don't forget to select this as the answer to help anybody that comes across it in future :)

Answer (score 0):

**// HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li class="item" data-done-state="true">Erster Eintrag</li>
    <li class="item" data-done-state="false">Zweiter Eintrag</li>
    <li class="item" data-done-state="true">Dritter Eintrag</li>
  </body>
</html>
```

**//CSS Code**

```
li {
  background-color: khaki;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

[data-done-state="true"] {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**//JS Code**

```
window.onload = function() {
  const nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".item");
  for (const node of nodes) {
    node.addEventListener("click", function(elem) {
      switchDoneState(elem);
    });
  }
};

function switchDoneState(elem) {
  const isDone = JSON.parse(elem.target.getAttribute("data-done-state"));
  elem.target.setAttribute("data-done-state", !isDone);
}
```